# mv: A and B are the same file

Tags: bash, find, mv, cygwin

I'm trying to move 5 .MOV files to a folder called MOV. I'm using `find` to list the files and `mv` to move the files:

```
$ mkdir MOV ; find . -type f -iname '*.MOV' -exec mv "{}" "MOV" \;
mv: './MOV/IMG_2391.MOV' and 'MOV/IMG_2391.MOV' are the same file
mv: './MOV/IMG_2395.MOV' and 'MOV/IMG_2395.MOV' are the same file
mv: './MOV/IMG_2401.MOV' and 'MOV/IMG_2401.MOV' are the same file
```

I don't understand why this is warning me, I moved the files back to the original location and this time I `echo`'d to see what it's doing:

```
$ mkdir MOV ; find . -type f -iname '*.MOV' -exec echo mv "{}" "MOV" \;
mv ./IMG_2391.MOV MOV
mv ./IMG_2394.MOV MOV
mv ./IMG_2395.MOV MOV
mv ./IMG_2400.MOV MOV
mv ./IMG_2401.MOV MOV
```

It seems fine, there are no duplicates.

If I name the destination folder something other than MOV, it doesn't warn anymore.
Also if I use `-maxdepth 1` on `find` it doesn't warn. Or I could simply use `mv *.MOV MOV`. But I asked this question to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

I found a similar question on here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143012/why-do-i-get-x-and-y-are-the-same-file-when-using-mv-even-though-they-are-c But the answer doesn't seem to explain the issue and the answerer says that they stumbled upon this later as well.

Comment: I should note that this issue seems to be replicable only on slow HDD's (?). Working with the same folder and same files on another HDD, the warnings did not appear at all.

Comment: Helpful command: `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$@" MOV; echo $(ls MOV)' bash {} \;` vs `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$@" MOV; echo $(ls MOV)' bash {} +` to understand the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `find` command moves files into the directory called `MOV` in the current directory.

The way you have written the command, it will also look for files in the `MOV` directory, and when it finds matching files there (which may happen if the `MOV` directory is not the first one to be examined or if you run the command multiple times), it will try to move these to the same directory where they are already located, giving rise to the diagnostic messages that you see.

To fix this, you may tell `find` to avoid looking inside the `MOV` directory:

```bash
find . -path ./MOV -prune -o -type f -iname '*.MOV' -exec mv {} MOV \;
```

This, `-path ./MOV -prune`, tests whether the current pathname is `./MOV`, and if so, it removes it from the search paths and continues with the next directory entry instead.  Otherwise (`-o`), it carries out the same tests and actions as before.

---

If you are using GNU tools, you may speed this up a bit by calling `mv` as few times as possible:

```bash
find . -path ./MOV -prune -o -type f -iname '*.MOV' -exec mv -t MOV {} +
```

Without GNU tools, you would perform the same sort of optimisation using an in-line script:

```bash
find . -path ./MOV -prune -o -type f -iname '*.MOV' -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" MOV' sh {} +
```

In both these variations of your original command, `mv` will be called only a few times with batches of pathnames instead of many times with a single pathname each time.

If you only have five files, these optimisations would not make much difference, but if you have thousands of files, it will potentially speed things up significantly.

Comment: This is the Correct Answer , because the Directory Contents are changing while `find` is running. But @Shayan claims "If I name the destination folder something other than MOV, it doesn't warn anymore." : I think `find` may still warn , no matter what we name the Destination Directory inside the Source Directory. Depends on when that Directory gets "Processed" by `find` & whether that Directory is empty or not : We can consider AMOV comes first before IMG , MOV comes after IMG , ZMOV comes last after IMG with ASCII (or Unicode) Sorting.

Comment: @Prem It depends in which order `find` sees the directories, yes, but note that the utility does not examine directories in lexicographic (alphabetic) order, but rather in the order that e.g. `ls -f` would display them in.  This is sometimes called "unsorted" or "directory" order.

Comment: Yes , I imposed that order only to explain my Point , @Kusalananda , that if the empty Directory comes earliest , then there will be no warning , otherwise there will be warning. It is not only that Particular name MOV , which OP was claiming.